# dask bootstrap action for aws emr only deploys to master node not worker nodes

Tags: hadoop-yarn, dask, amazon-emr

We've attempted to use the instructions and guidance from this page on the Dask documentation: 
https://yarn.dask.org/en/latest/aws-emr.html
to deploy Dask when we are provisioning an AWS EMR-managed Spark cluster. What we're finding is that the bootstrap action provided at the link above only deploys the Dask components to the master node and not the workers. Ideally YARN would deploy the required packages for Dask to all the workers.

I have provided the bootstrap action code below.

Has anyone else seen this, and/or can recommend how to resolve this?

Bootstrap action code follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
HELP="Usage: bootstrap-dask [OPTIONS]

Example AWS EMR Bootstrap Action to install and configure Dask and Jupyter

By default it does the following things:
- Installs miniconda
- Installs dask, distributed, dask-yarn, pyarrow, and s3fs. This list can be
  extended using the --conda-packages flag below.
- Packages this environment for distribution to the workers.
- Installs and starts a jupyter notebook server running on port 8888. This can
  be disabled with the --no-jupyter flag below.

Options:
    --jupyter / --no-jupyter    Whether to also install and start a Jupyter
                                Notebook Server. Default is True.
    --password, -pw             Set the password for the Jupyter Notebook
                                Server. Default is 'dask-user'.
    --conda-packages            Extra packages to install from conda.
"

set -e

# Parse Inputs. This is specific to this script, and can be ignored
# -----------------------------------------------------------------
JUPYTER_PASSWORD="dask-user"
EXTRA_CONDA_PACKAGES=""
JUPYTER="true"

while [[ $# -gt 0 ]]; do
    case $1 in
        -h|--help)
            echo "$HELP"
            exit 0
            ;;
        --no-jupyter)
            JUPYTER="false"
            shift
            ;;
        --jupyter)
            JUPYTER="true"
            shift
            ;;
        -pw|--password)
            JUPYTER_PASSWORD="$2"
            shift
            shift
            ;;
        --conda-packages)
            shift
            PACKAGES=()
            while [[ $# -gt 0 ]]; do
                case $1 in
                    -*)
                        break
                        ;;
                    *)
                        PACKAGES+=($1)
                        shift
                        ;;
                esac
            done
            EXTRA_CONDA_PACKAGES="${PACKAGES[@]}"
            ;;
        *)
            echo "error: unrecognized argument: $1"
            exit 2
            ;;
    esac
done


# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# 1. Check if running on the master node. If not, there's nothing do.
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
grep -q '"isMaster": true' /mnt/var/lib/info/instance.json \
|| { echo "Not running on master node, nothing to do" && exit 0; }


# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# 2. Install Miniconda
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
echo "Installing Miniconda"
curl https://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh -o /tmp/miniconda.sh
bash /tmp/miniconda.sh -b -p $HOME/miniconda
rm /tmp/miniconda.sh
echo -e '\nexport PATH=$HOME/miniconda/bin:$PATH' >> $HOME/.bashrc
source $HOME/.bashrc
conda update conda -y


# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# 3. Install packages to use in packaged environment
#
# We install a few packages by default, and allow users to extend this list
# with a CLI flag:
#
# - dask-yarn >= 0.7.0, for deploying Dask on YARN.
# - pyarrow for working with hdfs, parquet, ORC, etc...
# - s3fs for access to s3
# - conda-pack for packaging the environment for distribution
# - ensure tornado 5, since tornado 6 doesn't work with jupyter-server-proxy
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
echo "Installing base packages"
conda install \
-c conda-forge \
-y \
-q \
dask-yarn>=0.7.0 \
pyarrow \
s3fs \
conda-pack \
tornado=5 \
$EXTRA_CONDA_PACKAGES


# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# 4. Package the environment to be distributed to worker nodes
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
echo "Packaging environment"
conda pack -q -o $HOME/environment.tar.gz


# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# 5. List all packages in the worker environment
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
echo "Packages installed in the worker environment:"
conda list


# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# 6. Configure Dask
#
# This isn't necessary, but for this particular bootstrap script it will make a
# few things easier:
#
# - Configure the cluster's dashboard link to show the proxied version through
#   jupyter-server-proxy. This allows access to the dashboard with only an ssh
#   tunnel to the notebook.
#
# - Specify the pre-packaged python environment, so users don't have to
#
# - Set the default deploy-mode to local, so the dashboard proxying works
#
# - Specify the location of the native libhdfs library so pyarrow can find it
#   on the workers and the client (if submitting applications).
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
echo "Configuring Dask"
mkdir -p $HOME/.config/dask
cat <<EOT >> $HOME/.config/dask/config.yaml
distributed:
  dashboard:
    link: "/proxy/{port}/status"

yarn:
  environment: /home/hadoop/environment.tar.gz
  deploy-mode: local

  worker:
    env:
      ARROW_LIBHDFS_DIR: /usr/lib/hadoop/lib/native/

  client:
    env:
      ARROW_LIBHDFS_DIR: /usr/lib/hadoop/lib/native/
EOT
# Also set ARROW_LIBHDFS_DIR in ~/.bashrc so it's set for the local user
echo -e '\nexport ARROW_LIBHDFS_DIR=/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/native' >> $HOME/.bashrc


# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# 7. If Jupyter isn't requested, we're done
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
if [[ "$JUPYTER" == "false" ]]; then
    exit 0
fi


# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# 8. Install jupyter notebook server and dependencies
#
# We do this after packaging the worker environments to keep the tar.gz as
# small as possible.
#
# We install the following packages:
#
# - notebook: the Jupyter Notebook Server
# - ipywidgets: used to provide an interactive UI for the YarnCluster objects
# - jupyter-server-proxy: used to proxy the dask dashboard through the notebook server
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
if [[ "$JUPYTER" == "true" ]]; then
    echo "Installing Jupyter"
    conda install \
    -c conda-forge \
    -y \
    -q \
    notebook \
    ipywidgets \
    jupyter-server-proxy
fi


# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# 9. List all packages in the client environment
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
echo "Packages installed in the client environment:"
conda list


# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# 10. Configure Jupyter Notebook
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
echo "Configuring Jupyter"
mkdir -p $HOME/.jupyter
HASHED_PASSWORD=`python -c "from notebook.auth import passwd; print(passwd('$JUPYTER_PASSWORD'))"`
cat <<EOF >> $HOME/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py
c.NotebookApp.password = u'$HASHED_PASSWORD'
c.NotebookApp.open_browser = False
c.NotebookApp.ip = '0.0.0.0'
EOF


# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# 11. Define an upstart service for the Jupyter Notebook Server
#
# This sets the notebook server up to properly run as a background service.
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
echo "Configuring Jupyter Notebook Upstart Service"
cat <<EOF > /tmp/jupyter-notebook.conf
description "Jupyter Notebook Server"
start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [016]
respawn
respawn limit unlimited
exec su - hadoop -c "jupyter notebook" >> /var/log/jupyter-notebook.log 2>&1
EOF
sudo mv /tmp/jupyter-notebook.conf /etc/init/


# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# 12. Start the Jupyter Notebook Server
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
echo "Starting Jupyter Notebook Server"
sudo initctl reload-configuration
sudo initctl start jupyter-notebook
```

Answer (score 2):

The script you have copied from the dask website is a conditional bootstrap action.

The following line makes the script run on the master node only:

```
grep -q '"isMaster": true' /mnt/var/lib/info/instance.json \
|| { echo "Not running on master node, nothing to do" && exit 0; }
```

It checks the `instance.json` file for the entry "isMaster". If it is false, the script exits with 0.

> Ideally YARN would deploy the required packages for Dask to all the workers.

That really depends on your usecase. I have not deployed dask to a multinode cluster. Spark for example, allows you to specify zipped dependencies when submitting tasks, so one does not necessarily need to install them.

Installing packages on all nodes makes it easier to package the job. However one can run into conflicting dependencies pretty quick with multiple unrelated running jobs. One can also ofc start multiple clusters for each job.

If you uncomment the line, the code will run on all nodes. However, you might want only some dependencies to be installed on the nodes and more staff to be installed on master. In that case you could provide multiple bootstrap actions.

For example the jupyter notebook staff does not have to be installed and started on each node.

[Dask on yarn guide](https://yarn.dask.org/en/latest/environments.html#using-archived-python-environments) suggest to provide an archived environment on submit. Thus the scipt is written in way to run on master node only.